# Anyway to apply filter while btrfs subvolume snapshotting?

Tags: backup, btrfs

`btrfs sub snap foo bar` creates an exact same contents of subvolume `foo` as subvolume `bar`, except the subvolumes in `foo`.

What I want is excluding some regular folders too from the output (`bar`), such as `node_modules` and `tmp`; just like `rsync --exclude ...` does.

There are several ways to make this happen, for example:

- Create a subvolume for the each folder that is to be excluded. (Con: automatically generated folders can not be excluded as they are created as regular folders, such as `node_modules` in this scenario)
- Create a temporary subvolume, delete the unwanted files/folders (Most promising approach), then create the final subvolume from it.

Other than above, can we apply a programmatic filter while creating snapshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to create a snapshot while excluding files or directories. Here's what the BTRFS wiki says:

> A subvolume is *like* a directory - it has a name, there's nothing on
>   it when it is created, and it can hold files and other directories.
>   There's at least one subvolume in every Btrfs filesystem, the
>   top-level subvolume.
>
> As well as being like directories, subvolumes can be mounted
>   independently of the rest of the filesystem. **They are also the unit
>   of snapshotting**: you can make an atomic snapshot of a single
>   subvolume, but not a whole tree of them; **you can't make an atomic
>   snapshot of anything smaller than a subvolume (like, say, a single
>   directory)**. - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Subvolumes

Comment: ...because excluding directories would break the atomicity nature of snapshotting, right?

Comment: I think what you're asking for could be implemented, and without breaking atomicity. It would have to be done in the BTRFS kernel module because it implements the system call used by the BTRFS tools to create snapshots. See here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kdave/btrfs-progs.git/tree/cmds-subvolume.c#n626

Comment: Until its implemented, this should be the accepted answer then.